# Skip replacement formatting if AY2 is a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding new categories to a report and need to change my VBA code to incorporate those. I currently have specific values change in specific columns, but will need to add a way to skip over these depending on what information is in the data pulled. Currently, my coding is below and changes all of these values no matter what the category selected is. I need to add something that says IF cell value in AY2 is "Total Fresh Meat" skip all of this formatting and move to the next step. Any ideas?

```
Columns("Ay:Ay").Select
Selection.Replace What:="FRESH PORK", Replacement:= _
    "MARINATED/SEASONED PORK", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
    FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Columns("AW:AW").Select
Selection.Replace What:="TOTAL FRESH MEAT", Replacement:= _
    "MARINATED/SEASONED PORK", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
    FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Sheets("2. Geography Pull").Select
Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="FRESH PORK", Replacement:= _
    "MARINATED/SEASONED PORK", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
    FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Sheets("1. Weekly RMA").Select
Columns("h:h").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="FRESH PORK", Replacement:= _
    "MARINATED/SEASONED PORK", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
    FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Sheets("4. Reports 1, 4 and 6").Select
Columns("am:am").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="FRESH PORK", Replacement:= _
    "MARINATED/SEASONED PORK", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
    FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: `If Range("AY2").Value <> "Total Fresh Meat" Then.... End If`. Check if the value in AY2 is not "Total Fresh Meat", if it is not, then format.

Comment: You only need to check AY2, or you need to check row2 for each of the columns?